# What is the significance of the repeated occurrence of plane flying above?

Tags: analysis, super-deluxe

In *Super Deluxe*, there are multiple parallel stories going on but many times the camera focus is on the plane passing above. But what is the significance of repeated shots of planes flying above in most of those stories?